# Can't find Javax class in latest Jersey/Dropwizard version in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jersey, dropwizard, jakarta-migration

As I understand it, Jakarta replaced the Javax namespace a bit ago, and Jersey did the necessary work to support this change as of v3.0. I've got a legacy project that I've been trying to drag from Dropwizard 2.0.25 to 4.0.1 with some great deal of pain. It's a maven project running on Java 13. Right now I'm able to run `mvn clean install` just fine, but when running the application, this stack trace appears

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:237)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:231)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:98)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:59)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:91)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:88)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:88)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:781)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceBagConfigurator.init(ResourceBagConfigurator.java:55)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:335)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:296)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:261)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:339)
at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:633)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$2(ServletHandler.java:725)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:749)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:392)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:902)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
at io.dropwizard.metrics.jetty11.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:470)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:415)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
at io.dropwizard.core.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:52)
at io.dropwizard.core.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:67)
at io.dropwizard.core.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:98)
at io.dropwizard.core.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
at io.dropwizard.core.Application.run(Application.java:94)
at com.myservice.thisservice.MyServiceApplicaiton.main(MyServiceApplication.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
at       java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 77 more
```

I've removed all references to javax in my imports and pom.xml. There is one transient dependency on javax.inject coming from Google Dagger that I hope isn't causing the issue, but I doubt it. I'm explicitly excluding javax dependencies like so in my application pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
  <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myservice.myservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>api</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- this is a custom dependency for my company -->
  <groupId>com.mycompany.auth</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-auth-bundle</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.lz4</groupId>
  <artifactId>lz4-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
  <artifactId>semver4j</artifactId>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-json-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datadoghq</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-dogstatsd-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.coursera</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-metrics-datadog</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.coursera</groupId>
  <artifactId>metrics-datadog</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
  <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools-events-java-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And like so in my parent pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.32</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
    <version>${dagger.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>${guava.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
    <artifactId>semver4j</artifactId>
    <version>${semver4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.lz4</groupId>
    <artifactId>lz4-java</artifactId>
    <version>${xx-hash.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.inject</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-auth-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard-auth-bundle.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>${mockito.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-json-logging</artifactId>
    <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datadoghq</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-dogstatsd-client</artifactId>
    <version>${dogstatsd.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.coursera</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-metrics-datadog</artifactId>
    <version>${datadog.metrics.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.coursera</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-datadog</artifactId>
    <version>${datadog.metrics.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
    <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
    <version>${awssdk.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>${awssdk.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>${jedis.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools-events-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>${tools-events-java-client.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've included my parent and applicaiton pom.xml files, the stack trace and the context above.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the exact same problem while migrating to the Dropwizard 4.0.6. The problem was this dependency here:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So changing it to the appropriate one fixed this one for me:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
   <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.20</version>
</dependency>
```